# panic: unknown time zone local на Go 1.21

Tags: golang

При запуске программы у меня вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
panic: unknown time zone local
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/TheDifferentGuy/mysql-api/pkg/config.Connect()
    /home/network_fox/Рабочий стол/Программирование/mysql-api/pkg/config/app.go:18+0xdc
github.com/TheDifferentGuy/mysql-api/pkg/modules.init.0()
    /home/network_fox/Рабочий стол/Программирование/mysql-api/pkg/modules/book.go:18+0x13
exit status 2
```

И как я понял он мне говорит об этих двух файлах, первый который подключает мою программу к БД, а второй который создаёт объект.

Это код подключения:

```
package config

import (
 "fmt"

 "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
)

var (
db *gorm.DB
)

func Connect() {
d, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "ilya:Ilya@12@/simplerest?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=local")

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("It's running")

db = d
}

func GetDB() *gorm.DB {
  return db
}
```

Это код создания объекта:

```
package modules

import (
  "github.com/TheDifferentGuy/mysql-api/pkg/config"
   "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

var db *gorm.DB

type Book struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name        string `gorm:""json:"name"`
  Author      string `json:"author"`
  Publication string `json:"publication"`
}

func init() {
  config.Connect()
  db = config.GetDB()
  db.AutoMigrate(&Book{})
}

func (b *Book) CreateBook() *Book {
  db.NewRecord(b)
  db.Create(&b)
  return b
}

func GetAllBooks() []Book {
  var Books []Book
  db.Find(Books)
  return Books
}

func GetBookById(id int64) (*Book, *gorm.DB) {
  var getBook Book
  db := db.Where("ID=?", id).Find(&getBook)
  return &getBook, db
}

func DeleteBook(id int64) Book {
  var book Book
  db.Where("ID=?", id).Delete(book)
  return book
}
```

И я не понимаю как убрать эту ошибку.Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

В строке подключения `mysql` уберите параметр `loc=`. По-умолчанию сервер БД использует локальный часовой пояс. Ну или напишите там `loc=Europe%2FMoscow`, чтобы задать часовой пояс `Europe/Moscow`.

Comment: Я прописал loc=Europe%2FMoscow, и он мне теперь выдаёт такою ошибку -
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

Comment: @TheDude у вас MySql сервер запущен? Настроен принимать запросы по tcp?